# How to detect two gesture together and do a action?

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, xcode, uigesturerecognizer

I design two `UIImageView` on Interface Builder.

"`View A`" and "`View B`"

I've programed "`View A`" with a `TapGesture` , it can play "sound A"  when I tap that.

And programing "`View B`" with a `TapGesture` , but it can't play a sound with Tap.

But I don't know how to programing a action that [When I holding "View B" then tap "View A", it can play "Sound B"]

How to programing that?? Should I use `TapGesture` on "View B" is right? or change to `LongPressGesture`

thanks!!!!!

(sorry, my English is not good)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a long press gesture recognizer should be the best way.
Step 1, add a long press gesture in view B, and then hold it for further use(for example, save it as a property of your view controller)

```
UILongPressGestureRecognizer *longPressGestureRecognizer = [[UILongPressGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(longPressed:)];
[viewB addGestureRecognizer:longPressGestureRecognizer];
self.longPressGestureRecognizer = longPressGestureRecognizer;
```

Step 2, extend the view-A-tapped-action

```
- (void)viewATapped:(UITapGestureRecognizer *)tapGestureRecognizer
{
    UIGestureRecognizerState stateOfLongPressGestureRecognizer = self.longPressGestureRecognizer.state;
    if (stateOfLongPressGestureRecognizer == UIGestureRecognizerStateChanged) {
        // play sound B
    }
    else {
        // play sound A
    }
}
```

Comment: thank you so much!!


I'll join the apple developer member these days, and try to run on my iPhone.   


by the way, your image icon is very cool!